# Package agnostic symbol comparison

Tags: common-lisp

I have two packages each containing the same symbol:

```
(make-package "package1")
(make-package "package2")
(intern "SYMBOL" (find-package "PACKAGE1"))
(intern "SYMBOL" (find-package "PACKAGE2"))
```

and I want to compare them. I need to be able to write an s-expression like this:

```
(package-agnostic-eq 'package1::symbol 'package2::symbol) ; => t
```

**What would be the most elegant and straightforward way to do this?**

In particular I am interested in a build-in operator. Here is the function that I came up with:

```
(defun package-agnostic-eq (sym1 sym2)
  (string= (symbol-name sym1) (symbol-name sym2)))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`STRING=`/`STRING-EQUAL` takes as its arguments [string designators](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_s.htm#string_designator), rather than just strings. That means you can compare symbol names with it too.

```
CL-USER> (make-package :foo)
#<PACKAGE "FOO">
CL-USER> (make-package :bar)
#<PACKAGE "BAR">
CL-USER> (intern "QUUX" :foo)
FOO::QUUX
NIL
CL-USER> (intern "QUUX" :bar)
BAR::QUUX
NIL
CL-USER> (string= 'foo::quux 'bar::quux)
T
```

Comment: Thanks :) Can you, please explain what is a string designator?

Comment: The hyperspec has a [definition for it](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_s.htm#string_designator). Basically a string, a symbol or a character.

Comment: Personally, [I'd avoid all uses of designators](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27523651/800524).  They're useful for naming global definitions and for interactive development (mostly in the REPL), but when playtime is over, I prefer defining and using a `thing-name-=`/`thing-name-equal`.