# Destructive place-modifying operators

Tags: common-lisp

The CLtL2 reference clearly distinguishes between nondestructive and destructive common-lisp operations. But, within the destructive camp, it seems a little less clear in marking the difference between those which simply return the result, and those which additionally modify a place (given as argument) to contain the result. The usual convention of annexing "f" to such place modifying operations (eg, setf, incf, alexandria:deletef) is somewhat sporadic, and also applies to many place accessors (eg, aref, getf). In an ideal functional programming style (based only on returned values) such confusion is probably not an issue, but it seems like it could lead to programming errors in some practical applications that do use place modification.  Since different implementations can handle the place results differently, couldn't portability be affected? It even seems difficult to test a particular implementation's approach.

To better understand the above distinction, I've divided the destructive common-lisp *sequence* operations into two categories corresponding to "argument returning" and "operation returning". Could someone validate or invalidate these categories for me? I'm assuming these categories could apply to other kinds of destructive operations (for lists, hash-tables, arrays, numbers, etc) too.

Argument returning: fill, replace, map-into

Operation returning: delete, delete-if, delete-if-not, delete-duplicates, nsubstitute, nsubstitute-if, nsubstitute-not-if, nreverse, sort, stable-sort, merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, within the destructive camp, it seems a little less clear in marking the difference between those which simply return the result.

There are no easy syntactic marker about which operation is destructive or not, even though there are useful conventions like the `n` prefix. Remember that CL is a standard inspired by different Lisps, which does not help enforcing a consistent terminology.

> The usual convention of annexing "f" to such place modifying operations (eg, setf, incf, alexandria:deletef) is somewhat sporadic, and also applies to many place accessors (eg, aref, getf).

All setf expanders should ends with `f`, but not everything that ends with `f` is a setf expander. For example, `aref` takes its name from *array* and *reference* and isn't a macro.

> ... but it seems like it could lead to programming errors in some practical applications that do use place modification.

Most data is mutable (see comments); once you code in CL with that in mind, you take care not to modify data you did not create yourself. As for using a destructive operation in place of a non-destructive one inadvertently, I don't know: I guess it can happen, with `sort` or `delete`, maybe the first times you use them. In my mind `delete` is stronger, more destructive than simply `remove`, but maybe that's because I already know the difference.

> Since different implementations can handle the place results differently, couldn't portability be affected?

If you want portability, you follow the specification, which does not offer much guarantee w.r.t. which destructive operations are applied. Take for example [`DELETE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rm_rm.htm) (emphasis mine):

> Sequence **may be** destroyed and used to construct the result; however, the result **might or might not** be identical to sequence.

It is wrong to assume anything about how the list is being modified, or even if it is being modified. You could actually implement `delete` as an alias of `remove` in a minimal implementation. In all cases, you use the **return value** of your function (both `delete` and `remove` have the same signature).

#### Categories

> I've divided the destructive common-lisp sequence operations into two categories corresponding to "argument returning" and "operation returning".

It is not clear at all what those categories are supposed to represent. Are those definition the one you have in mind?

1. an *argument returning* operation is one which returns one of its argument as a return value, possibly modified.
2. an *operation returning* operation is one where the result is based on one of its argument, and might be identical to that argument, but needs not be.

The definition of *operation returning* is quite vague and encompass both destructive and non-destructive operations. I would classify `cons` as such because it does not return one of its argument; OTOH, it is a purely functional operation.

I don't really get what those categories offer in addition to *destructive* or *non-destructive*.

#### Setf composition gotcha

Suppose you write a function `(remote host key)` which gets a value from a remote key/value datastore. Suppose also that you define `(setf remote)` so that it updates the remote value.

You might expect `(setf (first (remote host key)) value)` to:

1. Fetch a list from host, indexed by key,
2. Replace its first element by value,
3. Push the changes back to the remote host.

However, step 3 does generally not happen: the local list is modified in place (this is the most efficient alternative, but it makes setf expansions somewhat lazy about updates). You could define a new set of macros such as the whole round-trip is always implemented, with [`DEFINE-SETF-EXPANDER`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defi_3.htm), though.

Comment: 'Most data is mutable' - though with literal data the exact effects are undefined.

Comment: Insightful clarifications, as usual! The two destructive categories I was trying to get at might be illustrated by the functions `(replace seq1 seq2)` and `(delete item seq1)`. Both destroy seq1 and both return a value. But only seq1 from `replace` seems usable following evaluation, independently of the value returned by the function (no need to `setf` the return value). Am I misinterpreting CLtL2?

Comment: @davypough That's just a result of how lists work. If `DELETE` removes the first element of a list, it may do it by just dropping the first cons instead of modifying it, in which case the first cons of the new list is not the same cons-object that started the list previously. So any variables that point to the old head cons aren't pointing at the head of the new list.

Comment: @davypough Some functions may only need to modify the content of objects, in place, by "reusing" the existing storage (e.g. map-into with vectors), in which case you can keep using the original objects, because only the *content* has changed; other functions are *more* destructive and might alter the structure being given, like "delete", "sort"; It is true that you can't portably reuse the argument after it was destroyed in such cases. I'd say in practice we don't care, whenever the spec says "destructive", one follows precisely the signature and use the return value (especially with lists).

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to address your question by introducing some concepts.

I hope it helps you to consolidate your knowledge and to find your remaining answers about this subject.

---

The first concept is that of **non-destructive** versus **destructive** behavior.

A function that is non-destructive won't change the data passed to it.

A function that is destructive may change the data passed to it.

You can apply the (non-)destructive nature to something other than a single function.  For instance, if a function stores the data passed to it somewhere, say in a object's slot, then the destructive*ness* depends on that object's behavior, its other operations, events, etc.

The convention for functions that immediately modify its arguments is to (usually) prefix with `n`.

The convention doesn't work the other way around, there are many functions that start with `n` (e.g. `not`/`null`, `nth`, `ninth`, `notany`, `notevery`, `numberp` etc.)  There are also notable exceptions, such as `delete`, `merge`, `sort` and `stable-sort`.  The only way to naturally grasp them is with time/experience.  For instance, always refer to the HyperSpec whenever you see a function you don't know yet.

Moreover, you usually need to store the result of some destructive functions, such as `delete` and `sort`, because they may choose to skip the head of the list or to not be destructive at all.  `delete` may actually return `nil`, the empty list, which is not possible to obtain from a modified cons.

---

The second concept is that of **generalized reference**.

A generalized reference is anything that can hold data, such as a variable, the car and cdr of a cons, the element locations of an array or hash table, the slots of an object, etc.

For each container data structure, you need to know the specific modifying function.  However, for some generalized references, there might not be a function to modify it, such as a local variable, in which case there are still special forms to modify it.

As such, in order to modify any generalized reference, you need to know its modifying form.

Another concept closely related to generalized references is the **place**.  A form that identifies a generalized reference is called a place.  Or in other words, a place is the written way (form) that represents a generalized reference.

For each kind of place, you have a reader form and a writer form.

Some of these forms are documented, such as using the symbol of a variable to read it and `setq` a variable to write to it, or `car`/`cdr`  to read from and `rplaca`/`rplacd` to write to a cons.  Others are only documented to be accessors, such as `aref` to read from arrays; its writer form is not actually documented.

To get these forms, you have [`get-setf-expansion`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_get_se.htm).  You actually also get a set of variables and their initializing forms (to be used as through `let*`) that will be used by the reader form and/or the writer form, and a set of variables (to be bound to the new values) that will be used by the writer form.

If you've used Lisp before, you've probably used `setf`.  `setf` is a macro that generates code that runs within the scope (environment) of its expansion.

Essentially, it behaves as if by using `get-setf-expansion`, generating a `let*` form for the variables and initializing forms, generating extra bindings for the writer variables with the result of the value(s) form and invoking the writer form within all this environment.

For instance, let's define a `my-setf1` macro which takes only a single place and a single newvalue form:

```
(defmacro my-setf1 (place newvalue &environment env)
  (multiple-value-bind (vars vals store-vars writer-form reader-form)
      (get-setf-expansion place env)
    `(let* (,@(mapcar #'(lambda (var val)
                          `(,var ,val))
                      vars vals))
       ;; In case some vars are used only by reader-form
       (declare (ignorable ,@vars))
       (multiple-value-bind (,@store-vars)
           ,newvalue
         ,writer-form
         ;; Uncomment the next line to mitigate buggy writer-forms
         ;;(values ,@store-vars)
         ))))
```

You could then define `my-setf` as:

```
(defmacro my-setf (&rest pairs)
  `(progn
     ,@(loop
         for (place newvalue) on pairs by #'cddr
         collect `(my-setf1 ,place ,newvalue))))
```

There is a convention for such macros, which is to suffix with `f`, such as `setf` itself, `psetf`, `shiftf`, `rotatef`, `incf`, `decf`, `getf` and `remf`.

Again, the convention doesn't work the other way around, there are operators that end with `f`, such as `aref`, `svref` and `find-if`, which are functions, and `if`, which is a conditional execution special operator.  And yet again, there are notable exceptions, such as `push`, `pushnew`, `pop`, `ldb`, `mask-field`, `assert` and `check-type`.

---

Depending on your point-of-view, many more operators are implicitly destructive, even if not effectively tagged as such.

For instance, every defining operator (e.g. the macros `defun`, `defpackage`, `defclass`, `defgeneric`, `defmethod`, the function `load`) changes either the global environment or a temporary one, such as the compilation environment.

Others, like `compile-file`, `compile` and `eval`, depend on the forms they'll execute.  For `compile-file`, it also depends on how much it isolates the compilation environment from the startup environment.

Other operators, like `makunbound`, `fmakunbound`, `intern`, `export`, `shadow`, `use-package`, `rename-package`, `adjust-array`, `vector-push`, `vector-push-extend`, `vector-pop`, `remhash`, `clrhash`, `shared-initialize`, `change-class`, `slot-makunbound`, `add-method` and `remove-method`, are (more or less) clearly intended to have **side-effects**.

And it's this last concept that can be the widest.  Usually, a side-effect is regarded as any observable variation in one environment.  As such, functions that don't change data are usually considered free of side-effects.

However, this is ill-defined.  You may consider that all code execution implies side-effects, depending on what you define to be your environment or on what you can measure (e.g. consumed quotas, CPU time and real time, used memory, GC overhead, resource contention, system temperature, energy consumption, battery drain).

---

NOTE: None of the example lists are exhaustive.

Comment: Pretty much everything you've said here (surprisingly) is beginning to make sense! So let me just try to comment briefly on the basics. Starting with a specific "lisp object" (eg, the number 3), it will be located at some specific "place" in memory (at some time). Object and place, thus, are different kinds of things. But a place, then, cannot "be" a "lisp form", since a form, like x or (car x), is a linguistic thing. However, a form can "refer" to either a lisp object or a place. It is the form that "is" a "reference". (continued below)

Comment: CLtL2 seems to distinguish between a "generalized variable" and a "generalized variable reference" (eg, p132ff), which remains somewhat opaque to me. You also talk about a "generalized reference" as "being" the "contents" of an array or ht, which is also puzzling. To me a reference is something that can refer to contents (like an object, a place, or other kinds of individual things), not "is" the content itself. This leaves "variable" and "generalized variable", which deserves more careful (perhaps mathematical) investigation. Thank you for a stimulating discussion.

Comment: I don't know why you're reading CLtL2 instead of ANSI Common Lisp, but it's just a naming difference. "Generalized variables" in CLtL2 are "generalized references" in ACL.  A "place" is a form that represents this, in both CLtL2 and ACL; CLtL2 uses "place" and "generalized-variable reference" interchangeably.  In the case of arrays, let me illustrate: the form `(aref array subscript...)` is a place, the generalized reference is `array`'s specific location determined by `subscript...`.  Different `array` locations are, naturally, different generalized references.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: OK, I can see that these meanings of "place" and "reference" have historical significance. But I also think it can impede the understanding of newcomers, since it conflates a number of subtly distinct concepts. Guess that's the price of entry to any technical field though. Cheers.

Comment: That's applicable to any formal specification.  Introductory literature, such as "Practical Common Lisp", is way more appropriate for beginners.  Personally, in this specific case, I always use "place" instead of "generalized reference" in comments, documentation and actual speech.  However, I usually use specific terms for less subtle differences, [such as "designator"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27523651/800524) when something can be an object of the target type or something that denotes such an object (e.g. package designator), although I avoid using them in code I write.